# How to allow anonymous access to SharePoint branding for a restricted site

Tags: authentication, anonymous-authentication, login, style-library, custom-login-page

I have a user portal with a custom login screen. You must have an account to access any content other than the login page.

I'd like to re-use the current branding that exists in our SharePoint, i.e. css styles in the Style Library and images in the media manager for the company's logo. I'm doing this using the `SharePoint:CssRegistration` tags for the style sheet. How can I grant anonymous access to these resources, and is this the best way to accomplish re-usability and content organization?

I'm wondering if I should instead store the css and logo images in the _catalog/masterpage area for easy reuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight forward way to allow anonymous access to the style sheets, was to add the .css file to the layouts folder itself, and reference this file rather than the css files in the Style Library.